# Custom Wordpress search results

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the standard wordpress search results from Title and excerpt, to Title, price and review stars (so it looks the same as the product category pages).

I've got some code that hides the exerpt, but I can't figure out how to add price and reviews.

```
.search .entry-summary {
display: none;
}
```

I also don't seem to have a search.php file in my theme.. There's a search plugin with my theme called LSX Search, but i can't figure out how this works or how to change it.

Could someone please help.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are some good answers here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195818/add-results-into-wordpress-search-results See **Include Custom Post Types in Search Results**

Comment: thanks do i want the code for "Include Custom / API Results"? how would I change it to add the price? Thanks